# Cannot read property 'queue' of undefined Discord Music bot

Tags: javascript, discord.js, bots

So i want to write a Music bot for discord using discord.js its one of my first javascript projects and i followed this tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=q0lsD7U0JSI but all i is this error message:**TypeError: Cannot read property 'queue' of undefined**

```
const {
    Client,
    Attachment
} = require('discord.js');
const bot = new Client();

const ytdl = require("ytdl-core");

const token = '';

const PREFIX = '!';

const servers = {};

bot.on('ready', () =>{
    console.log('This bot is online!');
})

bot.on('message', message=>{
    
    let args = message.content.substring(PREFIX.length).split(" ");

    switch(args[0]){
        case 'play':

            function play(connection, message){
                var server = servers[message.guild.id];

                server.dispatcher = connection.play(ytdl(server.gueue[0], {filter: "audioonly"}));

                server.queue.shift();

                server.dispatcher.on("finish", function(){
                    if(server.queue[0]){
                        play(connection, message);
                    }else{
                        connection.disconnect();
                    }
                });

            }


            if(!args[1]){
                message.channel.send("Du musst einen Link einfügen :D")
                return;
            }

            if(!message.member.voice.channel){
                message.channel.send("Du musst dich in einem voice channel befinden");
                return;
            }

            if(!servers[message.guild.id]) servers[message.guild] = {
                queue: []
            }

            var server = servers[message.guild.id];

            server.queue.push(args[1]);

            if(!message.quild.voice.connection) 
            message.member.voice.channel.join().then(function(connection){
                play(connection, message);

            })
   
            break;
    }
})
bot.login(token);
```

I already implemented the changes of discord.js v12 but that doesn't seem to fix it.

Comment: If `servers` is an empty object, `servers[message.guild.id]` will be undefined and it has no `queue` property.

Comment: but how would I fix that I am genuinely confused XD

Comment: The order of your code appears to be completely messed up. There is a part of your code below which checks for `servers[message.guild.id]`, and define it if it is falsy.

Answer (score 0):

I would set up a map as an independent queue and add values there. Servers is an empty object. It has no properties.